# What algorithm to use for getting a sub CIDR from a base CIDR?

Tags: java, algorithm, network-programming, cidr

I have a VPC and let's say its CIDR block is 10.0.0.0/16. And I have a couple of random subnets in that VPC. Their CIDRs could be something like 10.0.128.0/19, 10.0.32.0/19, 10.0.208.0/22. CIDR blocks for subnets must be covered by the CIDR block of the VPC. Also, no overlap of CIDRs among subnets is allowed.

**My question is:**
Given such a VPC and subnets, how to find a **good** CIDR block with specific size for a new subnets I want to create(let's say /22). The **good**, from my point of view, means better using of space. Let's say if I just want a small CIDR block, it shouldn't return me a CIDR right in the middle of the VPC CIDR, which prevent potential big CIDR block being placed in the future. Other definitions of **good** are welcomed. There is no guarantee for any initial states.

I don't know if there is a standard algorithm for such problem. What I am currently thinking of is making use of a binary tree. The left child means 0 while right child means 1. All leaves represent CIDR blocks that are in used. To get a new CIDR block, the problem is basically creating a leave at some level depends on the desired size of the block. How to create a **good** leaves I still don't know yet.

BTW, I am writing Java code. I couldn't find a library for this. If there is an existing library, please also let me know!

Comment: Here I found one library using javascript, I am sure you can write it in Java too https://github.com/pnutmath/subnet-picker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A binary tree is the right structure for this, but it needn't go down to the leaf level. Only take it down as far as needed. Every leaf in the tree represents either an allocation or an available block. By definition, the size of every CIDR block is a power of two. So, if a node/block has children, it has exactly two. If a node has children (is not a leaf), its block is *not* available.

So, your top-level block and its initial allocations breaks down like this (tree represented from the left edge for ease of drawing. `***` marks allocated blocks. [I've probably fat-fingered something here but the basic idea should be clear: every /16 has two /17 children, every /17 has two /18 children, etc. unless that node is available in which case it has no children.]):

```
                    /---- 10.0.0.0/19
                    |
            /---  10.0.0.0/18
            |       |
            |       \---- 10.0.32.0/19***
            |
     /--- 10.0.0.0/17
    |       \
    |        ---- 10.0.64.0/18
    |
  10.0.0.0/16
    |
    |               /---- 10.0.128.0/19***
    |               |
    |       /---- 10.0.128.0/18
    |       |       |
    |       |       \---- 10.0.160.0/19
    |       |
     \--- 10.0.128.0/17
            |
            |               /---- 10.0.192.0/20
            |               |
            |       /---- 10.0.192.0/19
            |       |       |
            |       |       |               /---- 10.0.208.0/22***
            |       |       |               |
            |       |       |       /---- 10.0.208.0/21
            |       |       |       |       |
            |       |       |       |       \---- 10.0.212.0/22
            |       |       |       |        
            |       |       \---- 10.0.208.0/20
            |       |               |
            |       |               \---- 10.0.216.0/21
            |       |
            \---- 10.0.192.0/18
                    |
                    \---- 10.0.224.0/19
```

So for example, to find a block of /24, first traverse the tree (in any order) looking for a block that is exactly /24 in size. If you find one, you're done; mark it allocated and return it. During the traversal, keep track of the smallest block you find that is *greater* in size than /24. (Obviously if you get to any node in the tree that is smaller than /24, you don't need to traverse its subtree any further since the size will only go down from there.)

If you don't find one that is exactly /24, you then go to the one you saved which is the smallest block greater in size than /24. You then cut that block in two, replacing it with two half-size blocks. Grab either one of those (arbitrarily). If it's /24 you're done. If not, you recurse to cut that block in two and so forth. Eventually, you will have found a /24.

Let's say that the smallest block greater in size than /24 was a /21. By recursively carving it up that way, you will have carved the /21 up into: two /24s (one you allocated, one still available), an available /23, and an available /22.

If a block is returned to you, you can combine it with its companion block iff that block is available (i.e. a leaf and not marked allocated). If you can combine it with its companion, you *may* be able to combine its parent with the parent's twin as well.

(BTW, this is compatible with @mcdowella's answer; just adding details.)

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer. From the above, I realize to allocate a block, a traverse of the tree is needed and the time complexity is O(V+E). I googled around buddy memory allocation based on @mcdowella's answer and found this post: [link](http://bitsquid.blogspot.com/2015/08/allocation-adventures-3-buddy-allocator.html). It basically maintains lists for different available block sizes. Find a block with specific size ideally will only take O(1) if such block directly exists. However, a tree structure works better for setting up initial states.

Comment: Yeah. You could always double thread your nodes too, so that in addition to being in the tree, each is in a linked list by block size. Then finding the starting point for your allocation is O(1). I wouldn't expect you'd need that performance hack though unless you're allocating blocks pretty frequently and you're allocating lots of small blocks.

Comment: Here I found one library that does this https://github.com/pnutmath/subnet-picker

Answer (score 0):

I think if you can find Knuth's description of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddy_memory_allocation (in "The Art of Computer Programming" Volume I) you will see various properties proved about it, and some of them might apply to the sort of tree-based allocator you are thinking about, which I think would boil down to something like this.

Keep track of the available address ranges as a set of blocks whose size is a power of two, aligned on a multiple of that power of two. If you ever have two blocks which can be merged to produce a legal block of the next largest size, you should do this.

When asked for a block of address space, allocate it from the smallest possible block in your set, and allocate a block whose size is a power of two. If you have space left over after the allocation, turn it into address-aligned power of two size blocks.

If a block of previously allocated address space is returned to you, add it to your set of blocks of size a power of two, merging it if possible with its neighbour block (its buddy).